# CSS nav bar not appearing

Tags: css, liquid-layout

I want to set up a page that hides a menu bar, depending in the size of the screen. I have it set up so that this menu bar is supposed to disapper when someone sets it to a mobile screen size (I believe 480px). However, when I assign the nag to display:none, it won't appear at all on the page. Here's the code:

Here is the url: http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/liquid/index2.html

```
<nav class="fluid fluidList hide_mobile">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="quiltshowphotos.html">Quilt Show Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="videotutorials.html">Video Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a>Services</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="quiltphotography.html">Quilt Photography</a></li>
<li><a href="photostofabric.html">Photos to Fabric Transfers</a></li>
<li><a href="download.html">Downloadable Patterns</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="photocredit.html">Photo Credit</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>
```

Here is the CSS:
    /* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

```
.gridContainer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 86.45%;
padding-left: 2.275%;
padding-right: 2.275%;
clear: none;
float: none;
background-image: url(../images/pattern2.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
min-width: 480px;
}
#div1 {
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

.hide_mobile {display:block} in the @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) area and then put .hide_mobile {display:none} in the @media only screen and (max-width:480px) area.

and let me know if that helps.